# isDisplayed not locating an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

From my understanding when referring to web element and initialisation is done through PageFactory.init it will look for an element at the time when you referring to it, but in my case isDisplayed throwing NoSuchElementException.

I would like to just check if an element displayed  yet, if yes do one thing if no do another and i end up doing spagetti code :

```
public CarParkBook addVehicleIfNotExist(Vehicle vehicle) {
    try {
        if (!carParkBook.vehicleInput.isDisplayed())
            carParkBook.vehicleInput.clear();
        carParkBook.vehicleInput.sendKeys(vehicle.getVehiclePlateNumber());
        carParkBook.addVehicleButton.click();
        return carParkBook;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        clickOnConfirmVehicleButton();
    }
    return carParkBook;
}

public class CarParkBook extends BasePage {

    private static CarParkBook carParkBook;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='numberplate']")
    public WebElement vehicleInput;

    public static CarParkBook carParkBookInstance(WebDriver driver) {
        return carParkBook == null ? carParkBook = new CarParkBook(driver) : carParkBook;
    }

    public CarParkBook(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }


public class BasePage {

protected final WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 5), this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is lot easier to not use page factory in that case you can do a simle thing to check weathere element is displayed or not.

```
if( driver.findelements(By.xpath("whatever")).size>0)  // if true your element is displayed.
```

But if you use page factory try with the following code, i did not try but it should work

```
@FindBys(@FindBy(xpath=”whatever”)))
public List<WebElement> desiredElement;
```

then use same logic as above, just check

```
desiredElement.size()>0
```

Let me know does this help.

Comment: Hey thanks man, you have any project of yours where i can see the patterns you used ? if you have some experience maybe you could help out over the chat ?

Comment: I can not show you any actual code. That is the policy. Ask whatever you want and if I can Help I will.

Comment: No problem at all, i do not know actually how to start a chat since i am new here, if you do can you send open a conversation, thanks.

Comment: Actualy I started to use the site few days ago. We need to have 100 points to create the chat room. So we can upvolt eachother but that maybe against the rules.

Comment: I will get in touch with you tomorrow, with some questions and hopefully you can help me out, i have designed well understood structure and i used most efficient approach , however, i am struggling to understand some things including how to approach WebDriverWait

Comment: Great, we can discus. I created "selenium midle start" so you can join . i will try to figure out how to invite you.Thanks, adn see you tommorow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224139/discussion-between-prozorov-and-gaj-julije).